# How do I convert one object to another?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface named **IDeviceId** that I use in my domain.  I also have several concrete classes that implement **IDeviceId**.  Each concrete class contains the logic for a specific type of **DeviceId**.  For example, I have **DeviceMacId**, which is simply a valid MAC address.  Another concrete class is **DeviceShortMacId**, which takes the last 6 digits of a valid MAC address and combines it with a fixed 6-character prefix to create a valid MAC (several legacy apps use only the last 6 digits).  I have a few other classes for expressing an ID, but the majority of them are all derivatives of the same data.

I'd like to be able to easily convert from any one of these classes to another.  My first thought was to create a static class and do something like **DeviceIdConverter.ToDeviceShortMacId(IDeviceId)**.

What's the best way be able to easily accept data in one form, and then convert it to another in a repeatable fashion (across multiple apps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a "best way" to do this, you're going to have to find a pattern that works for you and go with it.

Off the top of my head, based on the examples you presented I would do something like:

```
interface IDeviceId
{
    // Other methods
    IDeviceId ToDeviceShortMacId(IDeviceId);
    IDeviceId ToDeviceMacId(IDeviceId);
    // etc...
}
```

Then each of the classes would need to implement the conversion methods.  Now if you plan on adding a lot of other implementation (concrete) classes later, then this could get pretty verbose.  So what you might consider in that case is in each of the projects which creates a new implementation you also create extension methods like:

```
public static class MacDeviceIdExtensions
{
public static DeviceMacId ToDeviceMacId(this IDeviceId deviceId) 
{
    // Implement conversion
}
public static DeviceShortMacId ToDeviceMacId(this IDeviceId deviceId) 
{
    // Implement conversion
}
}
```

The extension methods approach is a lot more modular, but could also be a lot more code.

Comment: My ultimate solution ended up being more complex (and pretty domain specific), but this approach is what worked best for me.  A lot of good options in this thread besides this one.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to implement your own casting:

```
public static explicit operator DeviceShortMacId(DeviceMacId deviceMacID)
{
    return new DeviceShortMacId(deviceMacID.MacAddress);
}

public static explicit operator DeviceMacId(DeviceShortMacId deviceShortMacID)
{
    return new DeviceMacId(deviceShortMacID.MacAddress);
}
```

That way you can do:

```
DeviceMacId newDeviceId = (DeviceShortMacId)deviceMacID
```

With this approach, if some conversions are not possible, you can handle that yourself and throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: The `as` operator does *not* use implicit operators. It will *not* convert a type. Think `a is Type ? (Type)a : null`, but without the explicit cast.

Comment: Right. Forgot that. Thanks. And making them explicit for good measure. This stuff can't be implicit.

Comment: This seems close to what I'd like to do.  Where would I define these casts?

Comment: try this: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0160__Operator-Overload/implicitandexplicitoperatorcast.htm

Comment: @GregB It would either have to be in the class you're casting to or from, as you see fit. Granted it's not centralized, but you can still arrange neatly that all classes have their respective casts.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create constructors on all your IDeviceID implementing classes that accept an IDeviceID object.

```
DeviceMacID macID = new DeviceMacID(...whatever you do normally...);
DeviceShortMacID shortMacID = new DeviceShortMacID((IDeviceID)macID);
```

Example code

```
public DeviceShortMacID : IDeviceID
{
    private ID _ID;
    public DeviceShortMacID() { }
    public DeviceShortMacID(IDeviceID id)
    {
        if (id is DeviceshortMacID)
            this._ID = id.GetID();
       else 
            this._ID = this.ConvertFrom(id);
    }

    public ID ConvertFrom(IDeviceID oldID) { ... convert code ...}
    public ID GetID() { return this_ID; }
}

public interface IDeviceID
{
    public ID GetID();
    public ID ConvertFrom(IDeviceID oldID);
}

public class ID { } // I don't know what you return so I'm making up this class
```

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to have logic for converting from one class to another in each concrete class?  I thought it would be easier to maintain if all of my conversion logic were in one place (one class to edit if I add a new concrete class versus having to update all of my concrete classes).

Comment: The only logic you should need in each class is code for how it takes a genral IDeviceID and creates its own ID.  If it matters whether you passed in a DeviceMacID or a DeviceShortMacID then I don't think your interface is defined correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Call me old fashioned, but I kind of like the static method approach here. You'll have the conversion logic decoupled from your entities, with a descriptive method name to describe what each conversion does. You might also want to consider implementing them as extension methods.